# An INSERT INTO in MSSQL Server 2005 that groups by a column leads to unexpected duplicate key violation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, unique-constraint

I am executing a stored procedure on Microsoft SQL Server 2005.  The code in question has worked flawlessly for about 12 months, but is now failing on "duplicate key violation error"

How is it possible to get a duplicate key violation error with the following?

This is the error:

> Violation of Primary Key constraint 'Pk_temp_item_sales_details'
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.temp_item_sales_details'.
>   [SQLSTATE 23000][Error2627]

This is the SQL that is executed:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE temp_item_sales_details;

INSERT INTO temp_item_sales_details
            (item_id,
             last_order_date)
SELECT detail.item_no,
       Max(header.sales_invoice_date)
FROM   invoice_header header WITH(NOLOCK)
       JOIN invoice_detail detail WITH(NOLOCK)
         ON header.invoice_number = detail.invoice_no
WHERE  Isnumeric(detail.item_no) = 1
GROUP  BY detail.item_no
```

`item_no` in the `invoice_detail` table is a `varchar` whereas the `item_id` in the `temp_item_sales_details` table is a `numeric`, but I am only selecting numeric values with `ISNUMERIC(detail.item_no) = 1`

Comment: Make sure that `Truncate` statement is executed before the `Insert`

Comment: If you are concerned about accuracy then you should stop using NOLOCK. That hint is far more than "read uncommitted transactions" which is the common thinking. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invoice_detail item_no values that have a leading zero. In varchar syntax, `0123` and `123` are different and unique, but if you cast them into numeric, you will have a collision. I would strongly encourage avoiding converting primary key values this way if you can avoid it. If not, you will need to have an approach to handle this.

Comment: Item numbers with differing leading zeros was the culprit.  So the solution was to group by cast(detail.item_no as bigint)